# Ionic3 - After deeplinks, two-way-binding is not working ( Test code exist )

Tags: angular, ionic3, deeplink, two-way-binding

I have an issue with deeplinks which blocks angular's two-way-binding.

I made a test project in git. Please check [here](https://github.com/Taewa/ionic3-deep-link-error-test) (This is a simple ionic default project. If you have already installed `npm` and `ionic-cli`, just run `npm i`, `ionic cordova platform add ios`)

**Explain about the project**
**1. Working case**

- There are 3 pages. Home, List and Modal.
- Each pages have an `input` and this input's variable is connected
  with `test` variable. And this `test` is shown just under the `input`

Like:

```
<input (input)="testFn($event)" name="myTest"> 
<p>Hello {{test}}!</p>
```

- Every page, whenever I type in the input, it immediately reflects in
  `{{test}}`.
- Everything seems ok.

**2. Not working case**

- If you check `app.component.ts`, you will see deeplinks is set as
  `this.nav.push('ListPage');` and the url is `myapp://list`
- So in my xcode iphone emulator, I will open safari and type in the address bar as `myapp://list`. It will redirect you to the List page.
- **Since then, type in the input to reflect to `{{test}}` is not working** in the List page and the Modal page. But working in the Home page.
- In `testFn` function, I put `console.log`. When I test, console.log always prints properly. So I guess angular is not updating properly.
  ( If you don't see keyboard in xcode iPhone emulator : `cmd + shift + k` )

**My environment**

- Ionic Framework: 3.5.0
- Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.12
- Angular Core: 4.1.3
- Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.3
- Node: 7.10.0
- OS Platform: macOS Sierra
- Navigator Platform: MacIntel
- User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
- Xcode : 8.3.3 (8E3004b)
- Emulator : iPhone 5 iOS 10.3 (14E8301)

I tried also `ionic cordova platform rm ios` and `ionic cordova platform add ios` but no luck.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Thank you very much.

EDIT : I can use `ChangeDetectorRef`'s `detectChanges` to force to update the view. But I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: Try with ionic 3.4.0 once.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: I too face same issue...any updates ?